# Firefox ignores Response.ContentType

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, httpwebrequest

I have the following code that's essentially "proxying" a file from one server to another. It works perfectly in IE, but Firefox seems to ignore the `Content-Type` header and always transmits the files (MP3s) as `text/html`.

It's not a major issue, but I'd like to get it working correctly in all browsers, so can anyone assist? Also, if there is a better/more efficient way of accomplishing this, please post it!

```
FileInfo audioFileInfo = new FileInfo(audioFile);
HttpWebRequest downloadRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(audioFile);
byte[] fileBytes;

using (HttpWebResponse remoteResponse = (HttpWebResponse) downloadRequest.GetResponse())
{
  using (BufferedStream responseStream = new BufferedStream(remoteResponse.GetResponseStream()))
  {
    fileBytes = new byte[remoteResponse.ContentLength];
    responseStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);

    Response.ClearContent();
    // firefox seems to ignore this...
    Response.ContentType = Utilities.GetContentType(audioFileInfo);
    // ... and this
    //Response.ContentType = remoteResponse.ContentType;
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", audioFileInfo.Name));
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", remoteResponse.ContentLength.ToString());
    Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
    Response.End();
  }
}
```

Comment: "It works perfectly in IE" IE tries to second-guess the content type from the first x bytes of the content, so you're probably sending the wrong type (or none) either way.

Comment: Both remoteResponse.ContentType and Utilities.GetContentType(audioFileInfo) return "audio/mpeg", which is correct for MP3s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding a `Response.ClearHeaders()` before calling `ClearContents()` like x2 mentioned and sending the file as `application/octet-stream`:

```
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"blah\""); 
...
```

Works for me when I need to transmit downloadable files (not necessarily mp3s) to the client.

Comment: I'm not sure what Utilities.GetContentType(audioFileInfo) is returning, but the Loris' suggestion should work.
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't done so already, my first step would be to check out the headers using something like [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829) firefox plugin, or [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to make sure they what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The typical type for this is audio/mp3.  What issue are you seeing?

There's also a link [here](http://www.influenced.net/tag/firefox/) regarding Quicktime hijacking of MP3 files.

Answer (score 0):

Is the result the same if you use Response.Clear() instead of Response.ClearContent() only?

Answer (score -1):

I don't sure but maybe clearing headers and adding mime-type can help

```
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AddHeader("MIME Type",Utilities.GetContentType(audioFileInfo));
```